# jsTree does not render my JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jstree

I'm working with jsTree in ajax mode.

The return json data is in the following format:

```
[{"Name":"David"},{"Name":"Joe"},{"Name":"Leo"},{"Name":"George"},{"Name":"Keith"}]
```

And for some reason the jsTree doesn't render it as a tree.

Any ideas?

Comment: You've got a flat list of data.  What sort of tree are you looking for?

Comment: Your JSON is flat. It doesn't look like a tree. All objects are at the same level.

Comment: does it matter? as a test I want to see all in the same level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

imo jsTree does not support JSON structure you use. you have to follow structure described in the dcoumentation - http://www.jstree.com/documentation/json_data

e.g.

```
{
  data : "node1",
  children: [ { data : "node2" } ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ivan, you save my day.